# How to implement deep linking in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9, deep-linking, appdelegate

I have a problem with the implementation of deep links in my app. I am using a notification called accenggage which can be seen [here](http://docs.accengage.com/display/IOS/iOS#iOS-Registering). Once I Start the SDK with the conf set in the AccengageConfig.plist file in my code as indicated in the documentation, ie I do `Accengage.start()` in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method in AppDelegate, I noticed that the function that opens the url is never called. But it will print the payload in my logs, but I cannot get access to it, in order to use it in my code. Everything works perfectly if I comment it. Please have someone used this before to try to see where I go wrong. when I open the link in safari it will lunch the app but will not print the url as I requested and neither will it open the views concerned. I taught my problem was with the deep links implementation, but that is not the case, it is rather the Accengage that I am not using it properly and will be glad if someone could have an approach on how to get the url when the push is sent with Accengage. Thanks!

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print("url \(url)")
    print("url host :\(url.host as String?)")
    print("url path :\(url.path as String?)")


    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)


    if(url.host == "/details"){

        let Ads_details: CollectionDetailViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "CollectionDetailViewController") as! CollectionDetailViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = Ads_details
    } else if (url.host == "/profile"){
        let User_profil: UserProfileViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "UserProfileViewController") as! UserProfileViewController
        self.window?.rootViewController = User_profil
    }
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}
```

Comment: Have you added the scheme in your `plist`?

Comment: yes I did that too

Comment: Can you paste the url you're trying to open?

Comment: You should use the method `func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:])` in appdelegate

Comment: The method you're using is deprecated and may not work on latest iOS version.

Comment: I tried that function too but it is not called either. the url I type to test is safari is myurl_scheme://host/details, I also tried  myurl_scheme://details. but the url is not printed, when I also put a breakpoint there nothing happens.

Comment: When you're opening the url is App in killed state?

Comment: yes it is, but I tried both states too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170680/discussion-between-mukesh-and-foutse).

Comment: I tried implementing the deep link on a new project and it works, so I was using an SDK Accengage which I realized that it was what was preventing me to access the url once I started it. I edited my problem accordingling. Thank you @Mukesh for your contribution, I was missing where my problem was. Hopping that with this update I could get an inside on how to go about my problem.